# For loops computation in loop header

Tags: java, loops

```
int k;
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    k = 2*i-1;
    System.out.print(k+" ");
}
```

How would I write the above statement with the computation done in the header? I can't seem to figure out the syntax..

Comment: "How would I write [...] the computation [...] in the header?" **Why?** By doing so, you would create less readable code.

Comment: FYI you shouldn't compute `k` in the *header*, that would only serve to confuse and drive future readers crazy.

Comment: Assuming you don't need `i` other than to calculate `k`: `for (int k = 1; k < 19; k += 2)`.

Answer (score 4):

So I'm going to answer your question and suggest one minor improvement which moves `k` into the proper scope of the loop:

```
for(int i = 1, k = 2*i - 1; i < 10; i++, k = 2*i - 1) {
    System.out.println(k+" ");
}
```

I'm also tending to agree with the comments.  You probably should just leave the computation of `k` inside the loop body for readability's sake.  You can still put the declaration of `k` in the header if `k` is not needed outside of the scope of the loop.

Comment: Why is it needed to have k=2*i-1 twice?

Comment: @Dapper First to initialize, then to increment after each iteration through the loop. The for loop has the syntax `for( declare variables; exit-clause boolean; increment variables)`

Comment: It could declare only `k=1;` `for(int i = 1,k=1; i < 10; i++,k=2*i-1) {print k}` since the first value is always 1

Comment: @Dev.Joel Indeed it could, but I could then ask you what if Dapper decides to start at 2 or 3 or 4 or 100000?  I think that keeping the calculation in the initialization is better coding style.  It expresses the intent of the code better than just putting what might be seen as a magical number for the value of k even though there was a thought process behind it.